# What did Andrew Bell SC (as he then was) do, that no other barrister had done to Gummow J in 17 years?

Tags: australia

[Andrew Bell SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Bell_(judge)) got appointed to the Supreme Court of NSW, then NSW Court of Appeal from 28 Feb 2019 -, and now Chief Justice of NSW. He was Vinerian Scholar on the BCL, and got a DPhil.

Scroll down half way on https://justinian.com.au/archive/off-with-the-rent.html, which cites [*Australian Securities and Investments Commission v Hellicar & Ors; Shafron v Australian Securities and Investments Commission* [2011] HCATrans 294 (26 October 2011).](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/other/HCATrans/2011/294.html)

> > **Bell:** Well, your Honour, we do not know what the recollections were - - -
> >
> > ***Gummow:*** Just a minute, Mr Bell.
> >
> > ***French CJ:*** Just let Justice Gummow finish his question.
> >
> > ***Gummow:*** No, I am not going to finish the question.
> >
> > ***Bell:*** Sorry, I thought you had. We do not know what the recollections were but he was willing to discuss those with ASIC. He was not willing to discuss those with us. The fact that he did not have or may have had few recollections would be – may itself be significant if the court were to find that one would expect him to have recollections. This was a pretty major matter of public interest and public importance.
> >
> > **Gummow:** You managed to do something, Mr Bell, which no other counsel has done to me in 17 years on this court, but I will not say any more and I do not think it is funny.
> >
> > **Bell:** I do not know what your Honour is referring to, sir - I am just trying genuinely to answer your Honour’s questions. Now, the point is, there was a witness who ASIC should have, as a public interest body, no interest in securing findings of contravention and disqualifications on the basis of an imperfect record, no interest, whatsoever, and really - - -
>
> Don't you just love the occasional weird judicial brain snap?

Comment: Where did that quoted text come from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rick Sorry. I forgot the reference. Added now.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just from reading the transcript I would infer that when Gummow J said "Just a minute, Mr Bell.", he was asking Mr Bell to wait a minute before continuing with his answer. Perhaps, Gummow J needed that minute to check something in the papers or, in any event, get ready to absorb Mr Bell's answers. It was sort of clear that the judge requested a pause until further express sign to continue.

French CJ presumed that Gummow J was wishing to add something to his question before lettng Mr Bell answer them, but Gummow J expessly denied that: he needed a pause, but not for adding anything to the question.

Now, what Mr Bell did was that he did not give Gummow J that pause. He did not wait for his sign to continue. He just continued *despite* the judge's request to pause. Apparently, that was sort of thing no one else did to the judge in his 17-year career, and the fact that someone finally did did not appear funny to him.

Answer (score 1):

The issue actually arose a few lines earlier in the transcript:

> **Gummow:** He also seems to have said that he had 'few recollections' and did not recall - et cetera, the February meeting. So why do we assume that there was this - - -
>
> **Bell:** Well, your Honour, we do not know what the recollections were - - -
>
> **Gummow:** Just a minute, Mr Bell.
>
> **French CJ:** Just let Justice Gummow finish his question.
>
> **Gummow:** No, I am not going to finish the question.

Bell merely interrupted Justice Gummow. This is a serious breach of etiquette in an oral argument.

Comment: So what did Gummow J requested a minute for if he was not going to finish the question?

Comment: "Just a minute" doesn't mean, "Please allow me 60 seconds to perform a task." It means "stop." I assume the justice was just breaking in to call out the interruption.

Comment: Well, the whole thing looks like a total miscummunication failure of a bunch of arrogant assholes...

Comment: +1. Welcome to litigation.